# Set custom header in PHP and check it in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, header

(For obfuscation purposes): for each request, I want to run some PHP scripts first, set a header variable, check its presence in the .htaccess and then execute the requested script.

I've tried passing the variable via URL, but it seems a bit slow, and it's not clean. I also looked at PHP sessions, but I think there is no way to retrieve a session variable in an .htaccess file.

```
//index.php file
//some scripts
header("var1: 1"); 
header("Location: /"); 

//htaccess file
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP:var1} 1
RewriteRule (.*) Main.php/$1 [L]

//Main.php
echo 'Main';
```

The ( RewriteCond %{HTTP:var1} 1 ) never return (true) which created a loop of redirections to the index.php file.. it seems like apache provides only the first requested header?

**NB**. the objective is to clean the (Call Trace) provided by (XDebug), if someone provokes a (Fatal Error) he could view the (Call Trace) and easily find the (first script source path) which is hidden. That's why I think I must redirect to the .htaccess file to clear the stack trace.

Comment: Headers that you send to the client are not sent back unless the client is explicitly configured to do so. What you want are cookies, because cookies are HTTP headers that _are_ explicitly defined to be sent back. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Also, you should never leave XDegub enabled on a public website for both security and performance reasons.

Comment: @Sammitch yep it works :) thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can try define and defined to solve your problem.

index.php

```
define("bypass","no");
include "file2.php";
```

file2.php

```
defined("bypass") or die("Restricted access");
```